# how to make div clickable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
paramToExternalFile = 'all';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.background = '#D8D8D8';
div.innerHTML = '<a href=' + xml_list_externalFile_SNS1 + paramToExternalFile + '/' + letters + '>View All</a>';
div.id = 'view_all';
div.className='optionDiv_sns';
ajax_optionDiv_SNS.appendChild(div);
```

This is the javascript for creating a div in dropdown, but I want this div to be clickable.

As you can see I have given the link but it will work only when I click by using mouse on that link but it won't work when I press 'enter'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a click event directly to your div like this

```
div.addEventListener("click", function() {
   alert("You clicked this div");
});
```

If you want to support older browsers, you'll have to do a bit more work:

```
if (div.addEventListener)
     div.addEventListener("click", function() {
         alert("You clicked this div");
     });
else if (div.attachEvent) 
     div.attachEvent("onclick", function() {
         alert("You clicked this div");
     });
```

Comment: as u can see in my question i am using javascript for my code and and i modified                                     div.addEventListener("click", function() {    alert("You clicked this div"); });  **it works for me , thanks** for this. I also want same thing for enter event as i press enter it shoud do the same as click event , so let me know what i should modify in my code

Comment: @vishal - I don't think divs have an enter event, but if you're talking about textboxes, they have a focus event you could use.

Comment: I will tell you my problem , m using drop drown list in search and suggest and i am getting list according to my logic and max 10 values will get publist in drop down. At the end one more div i have added for viewing all the list and this div is clickable now as i have modified that div according to ur answer. but when i press enter that **div value that is 'View All'** get published in text box and replace the entered value and go to ** [link](http://localhost/View All)**. So instead of this **'View All'** I want that **text value which i enter in text box**

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFn() {
   alert("My div is clicked!!");
   // something else...
}
</script>
<div onclick="myFn();">My DIV body</div>
```

Is this what you want? or you can try this:

```
<div id="myDiv"> My Div body </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Works on not-ie
document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("click",function() {
    alert("I'm clicked!!");
}, false);
// Works on all
document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = function() {
    alert("I'm clicked!!");
}
// Works on ie
document.getElementbyId("myDiv").attachEvent("onclick",function() {
    alert("I'm clicked!!");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#view_all').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

Comment: Please note, this is jQuery not actual javascript like asked. Yes jQuery could be usefull for the OP, but for the sake of this question and answer to help a more broad public than only our OP here i think a note needs to be added

Comment: Says AJAX right in the title, so this applies.  Please read the entire post.  Please read: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events so you better understand AJAX event handling and how jquery fits in to these scenarios.  Flame elsewhere.

Comment: For all we know, the OP is a beginning javascript enthousiast without any knowledge of jQuery, all i said was: add a frickin note saying your code uses an external lib. Jeez long toes

Comment: @Sander I'm with you, even though I had to raise an eyebrow at "actual javascript". When you use a library you're still using actual JavaScript. But I knew what you meant. ;-)

Comment: Well, in my belief jquery is like a dialect, thus not the actual motherlanguage, anyway not the place for this discussion just happy someone caught what i meant

Answer (score 0):

```
div.onclick=function(){
  // whatever you want to happen here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnClick event to attach your Javascript function to it, like:

```
<div onclick="alert('clicked');">
 This is a div
</div>
```

To call the click function on pressing the Enter key you can try this untested code, it should work:

```
<div onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) DoSomething();"/>
```

On the other hand you can use JQuery for that which can make it easier, see this Untested code:

```
$("#idivId").keyup(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#DivId").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks to all this works for me, if i click by using mouse it is working perfect. Let me know if i press enter over div , i want same effect that i should hit that url which i defined in div